# Tracking First Quartile in GWD

Tags: javascript, html, google-web-designer

I have a troube with adding quartile tag in google web designer. 
Can I add it manualy by code, cause i want to track gif not video. So i can track that gif already play 25%, until 100% seperated by 4 quartile.

Need some advice please !

Answer (score 0):

In Google web designer you can't add any quartile events for a .gif files.
Quartile events can be set for Video and Youtube components.

Comment: how about audio ?